# Error when using readtable on xls files with text that extends past the cell

Tags: excel, dataframe, julia

I have tried using Taro, ExcelReaders, and am finally settling on DataFrames for it's ease of use. I have approximately 2300 (small) excel files that I need to merge. Each file contains a range of information,b ut the area that is an issue is the column that allows for notes. With about half of the sheets, the notes section does not extend the given cell area, but with the other ~1150, it does. While libreoffice/WPSoffice can open these files just fine, the previously mentioned issue causes these files to spit out an error because DataFrames is assuming there are more columns in some rows than in others.

When I go into an individual file, select all fields and enable text-wrapping, the files are read accurately, but this is not a good fix seeing as there are so many files. Another note, I have already set separator='\t'.

Are there any ways to either DataFrames to correctly read these files or another method to achieve the same results as enabling text-wrapping in all files? Thank you for your help.

EDIT: I have posted the error returned for one of the files below.

```
 ERROR: Saw 114 rows, 23 columns and 2643 fields
 * Line 1 has 25 columns

 in findcorruption(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::DataFrames.ParsedCSV) at /home/ale/.julia/v0.5/DataFrames/src/dataframe/io.jl:712
 in readtable!(::DataFrames.ParsedCSV, ::IOStream, ::Int64, ::DataFrames.ParseOptions{String,String}) at /home/ale/.julia/v0.5/DataFrames/src/dataframe/io.jl:788
 in #readtable#78(::Bool, ::Char, ::Array{Char,1}, ::Char, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Array{Symbol,1}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Bool, ::Char, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Bool, ::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::DataFrames.#readtable, ::IOStream, ::Int64) at /home/ale/.julia/v0.5/DataFrames/src/dataframe/io.jl:851
 in (::DataFrames.#kw##readtable)(::Array{Any,1}, ::DataFrames.#readtable, ::IOStream, ::Int64) at ./<missing>:0
 in #readtable#79(::Bool, ::Char, ::Array{Char,1}, ::Char, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Array{Symbol,1}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Bool, ::Char, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Bool, ::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::DataFrames.#readtable, ::String) at /home/ale/.julia/v0.5/DataFrames/src/dataframe/io.jl:945
 in (::DataFrames.#kw##readtable)(::Array{Any,1}, ::DataFrames.#readtable, ::String) at ./<missing>:0
```

Comment: How are you reading xl files using DataFrames? Are you converting them to csv from excel? It will help if you post some examples of the problematic files and the code you use.

Comment: Hi @aviks, I apologize for not getting back sooner. I found a fix to the problem, I just had to use `quotemark=Char[]` as an option in `readtable()`. I do not know why this works, but it does. As for converting the files, I am reading them as straight xls files.